# PDF file in WebView android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am trying to load pdf file in webview. but the text and images in pdf are not displaying clearly.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Code:**

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/downloadedfile.pdf");
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.NEW(channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()));
                raf.close();

                PDFFile pdf = new PDFFile(bb);
                PDFPage PDFpage = pdf.getPage(1, true);
                final float scale = ViewSize / PDFpage.getWidth() * 0.95f;

                Bitmap page = PDFpage.getImage((int)(PDFpage.getWidth() * scale), (int)(PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true, true);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                page.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                stream.close();

                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body bgcolor=\"#7f7f7f\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64+"\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
                for(int i = 2; i <= pdf.getNumPages(); i++)
                {
                    PDFpage = pdf.getPage(i, true);
                    page = PDFpage.getImage((int)(PDFpage.getWidth() * scale), (int)(PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true, true);
                    stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    page.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    stream.close();

                    byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    html += "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64+"\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
                }
                html += "</body></html>";
                wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Why dont you open pdf in google docs?

Comment: Thanks for your response..I already done it.. but the requirement is it should load in the app and it should have zoom, next and prev options.

Comment: Goolge docs have all the options like zoom,prev,next.

Comment: is there is another way to load pdf in an app...please tell me to move forward

Comment: yes I know but they dont want open in google docs..

Comment: you can open in default android pdf viewer app.

Comment: yes.. i done that too..but in the screen they want header and footer and in between that the pdf file should open..

Comment: is there any way to display pdf file apart using webview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43039/discussion-between-muppidi-nikhil-and-siddharth-vyas)